# Play store - Wishlist server error DF-DFERH-01 - ZTE Blade III

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play-store, system-error, zte-blade

My android was working fine until one day, i saw

> **Error retrieving information from server. [DF-DFERH-01]**

with a <kbd>RETRY</kbd> button.

This is happening only in the "My wishlist" menu. No errors before.

I have ZTE Blade III with android 4.0.4 Ice Cream Sandwich.

**SCREENSHOT:**

[image: My wishlist error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. First you have to go to Settings > Applications > Manage applications
>      Once here you go to the "All" tab.
> 2. Seek the Google Play Store app and press "Clear Data" button.
> 3. Then look for "Google Services Framework" or "Google Service Framework" application and do the same.
> 4. Then restart the phone, wait a minute and ready.
>
> I hope they work.

http://wikitechsolutions.com/6496/how-to-solve-the-df-dferh-01-error-when-you-are-into-google-play