# Error retrieving information from server [DF-DFERH-01]

Tags: google-play-store, 8.0-oreo

Error retrieving information from server. [DF-DFERH-01]

I have a Sony Xperia XZ Premium running android 8.0.0. I have a problem when trying to go to the play store app and selecting the music tab. I get this error 'Error retrieving information from server. [DF-DFERH-01]'. I have seen errors like this on other android versions where you can fix it by clearing cache, deleting, and re-adding the play store app but it does not seem to work here.

Please assist. Here is a screen shot of it.

[image: IMG:]

I have tried these solutions with no luck

- [Google Play error "Error while retrieving information from server [DF-DFERH-01]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812822/google-play-error-error-while-retrieving-information-from-server-df-dferh-01)
- [Play store - Wishlist server error DF-DFERH-01 - ZTE Blade III](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69212/play-store-wishlist-server-error-df-dferh-01-zte-blade-iii)

Please note that I am asking about Android 8.0.0 and have not found solutions for that. Solutions for Ice cream sandwich and lollipop have not worked.

Comment: Our [google-play-store tag-wiki](/tags/google-play-store/info) has a list of those error messages. And for your case, it links to [Keep getting message error retrieving information from server DF-DFERH-01 from the play store](/q/36321/16575) – have you checked that already?

Comment: @Izzy yes I have tried that exact solution with no luck, that solution is for Android 5.0. I think this may be a Sony Xperia XZ Premium specific issue on Oreo 8.0.0 because I tried on another device Sony Xperia XZ Premium with the same result.